# Characters visible in vi, but not in cat.

Tags: grep, cat, character-encoding

I have a 300 lines file with `^@` character between each characters in the file.

(I cannot post the entire contents for security reasons, so I am pasting only the first line)

```
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$ cat cl.txt
2015-01-22 03:00:01; local;
```

Now, when I `vi` the file, I see the same contents as following:

`2^@0^@1^@5^@-^@0^@1^@-^@2^@2^@ ^@0^@3^@:^@0^@0^@:^@0^@1^@;^@ ^@l^@o^@c^@a^@l^@;^@`

Since `cat` wasn't displaying the `^@` characters, naturally I thought grepping for a certain string would work in `cat`, but surprisingly, it wasn't.

```
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$ cat cl.txt
2015-01-22 03:00:01; local;
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$ cat cl.txt | grep local
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$
```

After replacing the null bytes with `sed`, file is now readable in `vi` and `grep` returns the result from `cat`.

```
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$ sed -i 's/\x0//g' cl.txt
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]$ cat cl.txt | grep local
2015-01-22 03:00:01; local;
[mercury@app01 ftp_logs]
```

Questions:

1) Why didn't `grep` work before replacing the null bytes, given that null bytes weren't getting displayed. Does it mean `grep` saw the `^@` characters even though it wasn't displayed in the terminal?

2) This makes me wonder whether it is recommended to use `cat -v` or `vi` to read files on production servers since `cat`seem to be good in hiding stuff?

3) The file in question is an auto-generated file from a Windows machine. Under what circumstances does the `^@` find its way into a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the file is probably little-endian UTF-16. Some apps on Windows seem to default to this, and it causes a lot of porability problems.

`vi` represents ASCII-Nul (numerically zero) valued bytes as '^@' (control-At). You can actually enter zero-valued bytes in `vim` with the control-shift-@ chord.

`grep` must see the ACII-Nul bytes, rather than interpret the file as UTF-16, and then seeing the Unicode code points for '2' or '0' or whatever. I don't see an option in the GNU `grep` man page for making it deal with UTF-anything.

`cat` doesn't show the ASCII-Nul btyes, the terminal emulator in question would show them, but whatever terminal emulator you're using is ignoring them. If you use `cat cl.txt | od -x` or better, `cat cl.txt | xxd`, you'll see the ASCII-Nul bytes in the output of `cat`.  If you see something like 'ffef' or 'efff' as the first two bytes of the file, those are the "byte order mark" promulgated by Microsoft against all common sense.

I'm not sure what to recommend to transliterate UTF-16 to ASCII or UTF-8, `iconv` maybe, but I've never used it.

Comment: So, basically `cat`'s inability to show the ASCII-Nul bytes got me confused.

Comment: @sree - `cat` just writes bytes (not characters!) to stdout. The way you invoked `cat`, stdout was the TTY of the terminal emulator. That TTY or the terminal emulator chose not to show the ASCII-Nul bytes and confused you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, `grep` sw the `^@` characters.  `cat` is printing the characters to the terminal, but they are characters you can't see.  Just because you can't see the characters doesn't mean they aren't there.
2. Your choice/preference, depending on which one works best for what you need.  Remember, though, that `vi` has the possibility to change the file.
3. `^@` is not a natural character.  The Windows program is actively putting those characters there.  To find out why, you'd have to ask the programmer.  Most likely, the Windows program is assuming that characters are 16 bits wide, and your Unix machine is assuming that characters are 8 bits wide.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.

`vi` knows about de file charset.

If you use

```
file c1.txt
```

you could see if it is a UTF-8 or a ISO file.

After that you can convert it with the convert utility

```
echo file iso-8859-1 is converted to UTF in order to be emailed
iconv -f 'iso-8859-1' -t UTF-8  $MESGFILE >>  $MESGENVIADO
```

Comment: Please [edit] and explain the "de convert utility"... does it converts from the german character set? What is the name of the command line tool  Also what is "de file charset"... is that the German character set? Or do you mean "the" and not "de"? Also when you say "vi knows about de file charset." what do you mean exactly?  Please [edit] and explain in your answer (not in the comments).

Comment: This has the potential for a good +1 answer, if you could explain how/why to convert the file