# how to remove the empty/blank lines from files that appears as @ from vi

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, perl, ed

when I open file by vi

as

```
vi file

Current partition replica assignment
@
@
@
@
@
{"version":1,"partitions":[{"topic")]
@
@
@
@
@
Proposed partition reassignment configuration
```

but  I try to delete this empty line

as

```
sed -i 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d; /^\s*$/d' file
```

or

```
sed -i '/^$/d'  file
```

or

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

still file is with the empty lines

how to remove the empty/blank lines ?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat related: [Characters visible in vi, but not in cat.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183089/characters-visible-in-vi-but-not-in-cat)

Comment: It'd be best if you used `hexdump -C input.txt` or `od -tx1c input.txt` to figure out what those characters *really* are.

Comment: Do you want to remove all lines that content a single @?

Comment: Do you want to remove all lines that content a single @ -  yes ( but they only appears from vi )

Comment: Everyone seems to be taking the question at face value that these are blank lines, assuming that these are NULs (despite the fact that vi does not display NUL like this), and forgetting the more usual reason that vi displays `@` characters in column 1.  A big clue would be if the question were to mention that these lines were in a different colour to the other text.

Comment: @yael what does `awk '{print NR, length($0)}' input.txt` show? How long are those lines?

Comment: @yael From the :prompt within `vi` turn on the no wrap option,   `:se wrap! ` All these long lines will be straightened like curled hair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are **not** empty lines, but lines that are too long to fit on the screen, even after wrapping.

```
$ perl -e 'print "foo\n", "bar " x 4096' >/tmp/file
$ vim /tmp/file

foo
@
@
@
...
```

This is what the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) says:

> In visual mode, if a line from the edit buffer (other than the
>        current line) does not entirely fit into the lines at the bottom of
>        the display that are available for its presentation, the editor may
>        choose not to display any portion of the line. The lines of the
>        display that do not contain text from the edit buffer for this
>        reason shall each consist of a single '@' character.

Also look at the `vim`'s documentation about the `display` option:

> When neither "lastline" nor "truncate" is included, a last line that
>           doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.

Do not confuse them with null bytes, which are usually shown as `^@` (notice the caret). Also, this behavior is not universal (it doesn't seem to be implemented in `nvi`).

Comment: Interestingly, one does not see this by default with nvi and NeoVIM.  nvi simply does not do this, and NeoVIM has `display=lastline` set by default.

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me. Probably your file should have dos null values...

To view:

```
vim -b file
```

To convert to unix

```
dos2unix file
```

Comment: dos2unix , still stay the @ in the file when editing it by vi

Comment: can u share the result of `vim -b file`

Answer (score 0):

Those are null bytes, I believe.  `cat -A file` would display them as `^@`

`tr` can handle those:

```
tr -d '\0' < file > file.new
```

Comment: Here's a way to create a test file: `printf 'foo\n\0\nbar\n\0\nbaz\n' > file`

Comment: still the empty lines exists ( from vi I still see @ )

Comment: You should do some research about why vi is displaying that character. You should also investigate the upstream process that is creating your data file with odd characters in it.

Comment: yes I will do ...